# want to know how this expression works?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, decrement

The question is:

```
int z, x=5, y=-10 ,a=4, b=2;
z = x++ - --y * b / a;
```

Just wanted to know the output and how --y will work for the negative value of 'y'. What will be the precedence of solving this?

Comment: TO know the output why don't you just run the example?

Comment: @Borgleader : yes ofcourse i can run the example but i want to understand the concept behind it..

Comment: Prefix decrement decrements the operand by one and returns that *before* the rest of expression is evaluated. Why do you think signedness of `y` has anything to do with it?

Comment: Look up "C operator precedence," study up on it, and predict what the output will be.

Comment: @jrok: means "y's" value will be "-11"???

Comment: @John : i am cnfused with * and /.. they have the same precedence..

Comment: @Arizvi yes, exactly.  The "associativity" column tells you which order to evaluate the expressions in, if they have the same precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int z, x=5, y=-10 ,a=4, b=2;
z = x++ - --y * b / a;
z = 5++ - --(-10) * 2 / 4 // Suffix ++/-- goes first
z = 5 - --(-10) * 2 / 4 // Prefix ++/-- is next
z = 5 - (-11) * 2 / 4 // and then * and /
z = 5 - (-22) / 4
z = 5 - (-5)
z = 10
```

Unlike y, x keeps it's value because in suffix notation the operator returns the original value not the modified one. (Someone else linked the operator precedence page so I won't)

Answer (score 2):

It will be evaluated based on the Operator Precedence or "Order of Operations" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

These two are equivelent according to [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

```
z = x++ - --y * b / a; 

z = (x++) - (((--y) * b) / a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The *precedence* of the operations is

```
z = ((x++) - (((--y) * b) / a));
```

IOW,

1. The result of `--y` must be known before computing `--y * b`;
2. The result of `--y * b` must be known before computing `--y * b / a` (`*` and `/` have the same precedence, but are left-associative, so `a / b * c` would be parsed as `(a / b) * c`);
3. The result of `x++` must be known before computing `x++ - --y * b / a`
4. And finally, the result of `x++ - --y * b / a` must be known before assigning the result to `z`.

*However*...

Note that *precedence* is not the same thing as *order of evaluation*.  Each of the individual expressions `x++`, `--y`, `b`, and `a` may be evaluated *in any order*.  The compiler may choose to evaluate `x++`, then `a`, then `b`, then `--y`.  The compiler may choose to evaluate `--y * b / a` before evaluating `x++`.  The compiler may choose to defer applying the side effects to `x++` and `--y` until after the assignment of the result to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

`y` will decrement before the `=` operation because the `--` precedes `y` and 
`x` will increment AFTER the `=` operation because the `++` is after the `x`.

for example:

```
int i = 2, y = 3, z;
z = ++i + ++y;         //3 + 4
```

or

```
int i = 2, y = 3, z;
z = --i + --y;         //1 + 2
```

and

```
int i = 2, y = 3, z;
z = i++ + y++;         //2 + 3
```

Notice in the last example that it is still 2 + 3. That is because the `++` is after `i` and `y` so they are incremented after the `=` statement.

Knowing this, just apply your normal order of operations 
`(1. Parentheses 2. Exponents 3. Multiplication/Divison 4. Addition/Subtraction)` to solve the problem. Since the multiplication and division segments are right next to eachother just read from left to right for that part.

```
int z, x=5, y=-10 ,a=4, b=2;
z = x++ - --y * b / a;
y = --y
y = -11
z = 5 - -11 * 2 / 4
z = 5 - -22 / 4
z = 5 - -5
z = 10
x = 5++
x = 6
```

That's my thought process for this: I interperet the values of `x` and `y` based off the location of the `++` and `--` and then first mulitply `-y * b` and then divide that value by `a` and then add that value to `x` and then finally increment `x`. Remember when multiplication and division are right next to each-other just read left to right.

Comment: i am cnfused with * and /.. they have the same precedence.. should i evaluate them left to right??